# Why would Bscscan not recognize deployed contract as a contract?

Tags: bscscan

Deployed ICHIVault contract on Bsc: 0xE4CfCC79F760eD63f35Ec58a9d1fbE084DdE5C22
The contract is working, I am able to run various transactions using scripts and ABI. But it isn't recognized as being a contract in Bscscan. It shows up as a wallet instead.
Why could it be? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Working now. Possibly a kind soul can explain why it took so long?

Comment: Bscscan is a closed source third party block explorer. Unless someone working in the company says something we can only speculate, they could have had service outage for a couple of hours. Next time I'd suggest to contact their customer support. I never seen a question about the bscscan nor etherscan answered here.

Answer (score 1):

4 hours later, Bscscan auto-fixed this problem. So I suppose a solution in this case is simply to wait